# How to : Change an icon in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, icons, inkscape, icon-themes

Is it possible to replace a particular icon with one of our choice in 16.04 Ubuntu ? If yes, kindly share.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Which kind of icon do you want to change?

Comment: I have installed a software. It's added through PPA. How can I change it's default icon on desktop, dash and launcher ?

Comment: Can I know the name of said software?

Comment: Sure. It's called Peek. A screen recorder.

Comment: @karel , 12.04 and 16.04 are distant versions. Would an answer for XP will be relevant in Windows 10 ?

Comment: I am just curious. How are the questions same ?

Comment: Well, both questions want to achieve the same, change the icon of a .desktop file, and the method hasn't changed from 12.04 to 16.04

Comment: Yes, I noticed. You reply was very helpful and in detail. Without which I would not have been able to solve. I did add an icon to the icon theme using the method you described.

Comment: Im glad you managed :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### How to change the icon of a **Unity Launcher**:

**Unity Launchers** are files stored in your computer, with a `.desktop` extension. These files are used to launch a specific application, but in Unity they are also used so as to create right-click menus for each application, which you can access from the Unity Launcher.

Such file looks something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/$USER/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/$USER/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Icon field is the icon that should be used by the launcher and represents the application. All icons that are under the directory `/usr/share/pixmaps` don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension.

For example, if the icon file is `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`, then the Icon field should be just `wallch`. All other icons should have their full path specified.

---

Therefore, in order to change the icon for a specific program, you need to:

**1.** **Find** the related `.desktop` file, they are commonly under `/usr/share/...`.

You can do so with:

```
locate program_name.desktop
```

or if you can't seem to find it:

```
locate .desktop
```

and scroll through the list.

**2.** **Open** the `.desktop` you want to modify:

```
gedit /path/to/program_name.desktop
```

**3.** **Modify** any of the fields you wish:

Just to be save, make a backup first, which you can replace for the original file in case you screw up:

```
cp /path/to/program_name.desktop /path/to/program_name_backup
```

---

**Source and further information:**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: I installed an icon theme. That seems to be a lot easier than me meddling with all this. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: `locate *.desktop` did not return results to me, however `locate .desktop` did return many results!