# Chrome web application: change icon

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, icons

I created some icons on my launcher using Google Chrome's "Add to desktop" tool.  I would like to change the icon however.

Where are the corresponding .desktop files that represent my Google Chrome apps?

From there I imagine I can use the following instructions to change the icon: [How to : Change an icon in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894990/how-to-change-an-icon-in-16-04)

Comment: similar or the same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/33323/how-can-i-change-the-google-chrome-webapp-icon/1181688#1181688 ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the easiest and fastest way.

Install Menu Editor:

```
sudo apt install menulibre
```

Open Menu Editor, Select App, Click on icon to select a new icon:

[image]

Comment: worked well for me and was easy (on PopOS)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the really late delay, I hope you found a solution to this but if not I'm here to help!

I was recently trying to do the same thing and after some digging around I found the .desktop file located under `~/.local/share/applications`. It had a name like `chrome-randomestringhere-Default.desktop` I was able to find which one it was by doing a quick grep in this directory for the name I saved the icon as.

```
grep -r DesktopIconName ~/.local/share/applications
```

After this you are correct that you can change the icon logo using the methods described in the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks!  I've done some digging since then and I actually found 3 '.desktop' files being created every time I used the Chrome "add to desktop" tool.  One in each of these locations:
/home/selah/.gnome/apps/chrome*.desktop,
/home/selah/.local/share/applications/chrome*.desktop,
/home/selah/Desktop/chrome*.desktop

Does the same happen with you?

Answer (score 0):

You can change icons from Chrome's Apps by:

1. Right click start menu and click config/setup
2. Go to Menu tab and click Open Menu Editor
3. Go to Chrome Apps, select the App you want to change icon and click property
4. Click in the icon image and there you will be prompted to select icon

My SO is in Portuguese, so I don't know the exact button names.