# Separate launcher icon for teams webapp (using chromium)

Tags: launcher, chromium, webapps, 23.10

I created a launcher with the filename Teams.desktop. and put it in the folder ~/Desktop/ and created a symlink for applications `sudo ln -s ~/Desktop/Teams.desktop /usr/share/applications/Teams.desktop`.

The icon on the desktop is correct [image]

I can also "Pin to dash" it will show correctly in the launcher [image],

but as soon as I open it, the app will be grouped together with the chromium icon in the launcher.
[image]

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
```

will show

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "teams.microsoft.com", "teams-webapp"
```

lg shows [image]

This is the Teams.desktop file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=teams-wepapp
GenericName=teams-wepapp
Exec=chromium-browser --user-data-dir=~/.config/teams-wepapp/ --app=https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/ --class=teams-wepapp --name=teams-webapp
StartupWMClass=teams-webapp
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/marc/.local/icons/teams.svg
Categories=WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
```

I would really like to have a second icon for teams (or even two as I'm using two teams accounts) to switch more easily and not having to search through all open chromium windows.

I tried using [menulibre](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935559/chrome-web-application-change-icon) and a couple of instructions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935559/chrome-web-application-change-icon), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112571/how-can-i-start-a-separate-instance-not-profile-of-chromium-with-its-own-icon) and [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=406217), it doesn't work. Maybe there are some changes in 23.10?

```
$ ps -e | grep tty
   3556 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-wayland-ses
   3567 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b


$ ps -ef | grep -i tty
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
marc        3556    3432  0 Jan31 tty2     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
marc        3567    3556  0 Jan31 tty2     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
marc       93693   64482  0 16:17 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i tty
```

Answer (score 0):

If finally found the solution on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1891649). Using a different path for chromium:

```
Exec=/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome [...]
```

instead of

```
Exec=chromium-browser [...]
```