# '.desktop' file doesn't show up in 'ls' command list

Tags: permissions, 17.10, icons, .desktop

I installed Visual Studio but it doesn't show the icon of the app. So I was following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894990/how-to-change-an-icon-in-16-04) to set an icon.

When I go into `/usr/share/applications` I see the `.desktop` file of **Visual Studio Code** . But as I don't have access I can't edit it. So I opened terminal and tried to open it with `sudo gedit`. So for that first I tried to check the name with `ls`. But it doesn't list down the icon. 
[image: Visual Studio Code in /usr/share/applications]
[image]

Why is that? How can I edit `.desktop` of vscode to set the icon?

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't show in `ls` command. But I changed the icon by opening the folder with `sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications`

Comment: Maybe the actual name of the `.desktop` file is something completely different. The top-half of your `ls`-output is missing in the screenshot.

Comment: To add to what pomsky said, each `.desktop` file has a `Name` property that can be different from the actual file name. In the terminal you will see the filename, but in Nautilus you will see the `Name` property (or possibly a translated version of it it).

Comment: @devius +1 I have just wrote the answer in such manner. I hope it helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Files/folders prefixed with `.` are “hidden” from `ls` unless the `-a` flag is specified.

Comment: @eggyal It has nothing to do with that, files are of the form `filename.desktop`, not starting with a `.`. The file is not actually invisible, the name being displayed in Nautilus is different.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. The ls output should be posted as text with code formatting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of editing the `.desktop` file located at `/usr/share/applications/` (can cause many issues, will be overridden after an upgrade of the associated package) you can first copy the file and paste at `~/.local/share/applications/`. Then edit the copied file using gedit, `sudo` is not required.

**Why `ls` doesn't list down the file:**
`ls` lists the actual `filename.desktop` whereas Nautilus shows the name of the application as per the `Name=` field in `filename.desktop`. These two can be different. Here in this case `Name=Visual Studio Code` in the `filename.desktop`, but `filename` may be something completely different.

Comment: Thanks.  It was a conflict between vscode icon name and vscode icon name in numix theme. Changed the icon name from `code` to `vscode` and fixed the issue.(Of course I copied it to  `~/.local/share/applications/`). DIdn't use a png.

Comment: But why doesn't `ls` doesn't list down the file ?

Comment: @PankajaParanavitharana `ls` lists the actual `filename.desktop` whereas Nautilus shows the name of the application as per the `Name=` field in `filename.desktop`. These two can be different. Here in this case `Name=Visual Studio Code` in the `filename.desktop`, but `filename` may be something completely different.

Answer (score 7):

Usually icon name in Nautilus or other file-manager opened in `/usr/share/applications/`  may not be equal to name of `.desktop` file.

The correct way is to check `.desktop` file contents as follows:

1. if we know executable name (`code` in that case)

   ```
   grep -ir Exec=.*code /usr/share/applications/
   ```
2. if we know user-friendly name (*Visual Studio Code*)

   ```
   grep -ir Name=.*Visual /usr/share/applications/
   ```

And then you can copy this file to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit its `Icon=` field here.

Also you should read [.desktop file specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) to know how it works.

Comment: But why doesn't `ls` doesn't list down the file name ?

Comment: See my comment to your question above for that.

Comment: You can try to execute first command, then you will know desktop file name. Then of course you can do `ls /usr/share/applications/real-name-vs-code.desktop`.